# How to have Extensible Partial Output Caching in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm having no problem using [Extensible Output Caching .NET 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/27/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) on any view.
But I can't extend the output caching (on a disk) for a partial view(RenderAction).